# How button and ul of dropdown are connected?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

It's from the official documentation of **Boostrap**. I've deleted the `aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"` attribute from the `<ul>` element.

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

How can you link the button so it knows what to drop down?

Comment: Some of us can't answer immediately: sometimes we get caught by feeding the cats or sucking on those cherry young babes. Thank you for your answer, now seems clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that same Bootstrap documentation:

> Wrap the dropdown’s toggle (your button or link) and the dropdown menu within `.dropdown`, or another element that declares `position: relative;`. Dropdowns can be triggered from `<a>` or `<button>` elements to better fit your potential needs.

So I assume the button looks for a sibling with `.dropdown-menu`, and toggles that.

If you need to know in more depth, check the source code's method `show()`:

> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/dropdown.js#L150

This is the line that actually toggles:

> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/dropdown.js#L208

This is the function that finds the menu element:

> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/dropdown.js#L282

```
_getMenuElement() {
  const parent = Dropdown.getParentFromElement(this._element)

  return SelectorEngine.findOne(Selector.MENU, parent)
}
```

and that constant is declared [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/dropdown.js#L63):

```
const Selector = {
  /* ... */
  MENU: '.dropdown-menu',
  /* ... */
}
```

So, exactly what I was assuming.